# invariance of correlation to linear transformation: $\text{corr}(aX+b, cY+d) = \text{corr}(X,Y)$

Tags: self-study, correlation, linear-algebra, mathematical-statistics

This is actually one of the problems in [Gujarati's Basic Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073375772) 4th edition (Q3.11) and says that the correlation coefficient is invariant with respect to the change of origin and scale, that is $$\text{corr}(aX+b, cY+d) = \text{corr}(X,Y)$$ where $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ are arbitrary constants.

But my main question is the following:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be paired observations and suppose $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, i.e. $\text{corr}(X,Y)>0$. I know that $\text{corr}(-X,Y)$ would be negative based on intuition. However if we take $a=-1, b=0, c=1, d=0$, it follows that $$\text{corr}(-X,Y) = \text{corr}(X,Y) >0$$ which does not make sense.

I would appreciate if someone can point out the gap. Thanks.

Comment: If the book really says what you say it says, it's wrong; you need $ac>0$

Comment: @Glen_b Yea I do think the book state it wrongly, unless I am blind since I do not really see any conditions imposed on the constants.

Comment: It may be that scale is understood as a positive quantity.

Comment: @Xi'an It could be, but I do not think it is stated in the book. But thanks a lot for the edit and the answer by the way :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since $$\text{corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\text{var}(X)^{1/2}\,\text{var}(Y)^{1/2}}$$
and $$\text{cov}(aX+b,cY+d)=ac\,\text{cov}(X,Y)$$
the equality$$\text{corr}(aX+b, cY+d) = \text{corr}(X,Y)$$only holds when $a$ and $c$ are both positive or both negative, i.e. $ac>0$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that:

1. COR(a X + b, c Y + d) = V(a X + b, c Y + d)/(V(a X + b) V(c Y + d))^0.5.
2. V(a X + b, c Y + d) = V(a X, c Y) = a c V(X, Y).
3. V(a X + b) = V(a X) = a^2 V(X).
4. V(c Y + d) = V(c Y) = c^2 V(Y).

Combining all of the above:

- COR(a X + b, c Y + d) = a c V(X, Y) / (a^2 c^2 V(X) V(Y))^0.5 = a c COR(X, Y) / (|a| |c|) = sign(a) sign(c) COR(X, Y).

So COR(a X + b, c Y + d) equals COR(X, Y) for a c >= 0, and -COR(X, Y) for a c < 0.